Is this a good way to organize a combat system where different each shot could have a different effect in gdscript
None of the code is meant to work yet it's just an outline for general structure
Def func damage_Type(bullet) 
    If bullet = 1     
        enemy_Health – 100     
    If bullet = 2     
        enemy_Health – (50*speed)     
     
Def func support_Type(bullet)     
    If bullet = 1     
        enemy_Health + 100     
    If bullet = 2     
        speed + 100      

Def func status_Type(bullet)     
    If bullet = 1     
        apply_Fire()             
    If bullet = 2     
        apply_Oil() 
    Var bullet = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1]         
    Var types = [3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3]      
    If left click     
        Var bullet_Posititon = bullet_Posititon + 1 
        Var type = types[bullet_Positition] 
        Var bullet_Shot = bullet[bullet_Positition] 
        If type = 1 
            damage_Type(bullet)     
        If type  = 2 
            support_Type(bullet)     
        If type = 3     
            status_Type(bullet) 

I thinking breaking it up like this would be the best way to reduce if statements and prevent slowdowns as more and more add. I am new to gdscript and programming in general so anything helps.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your formatting was not very clear, I've submitted an edit.
About the question: you don't need to worry about "slowdowns" for a bunch of if's, computers process such simple flow controls very quickly. The syntax is all wrong though, try with actual code.

Now I'll have to preface this by saying, it has been a while since I written in GDScript.
But you do not have start defining functions by using Def, but all you have to do is use func name():
Here's an example of how functions are used in Godot
Besides this, I would recommend placing var at the top of your code.
Also, what is the idea here? Because it seems like you're trying to do an array.

alright and yes I am trying to use an array is that not how they are formatted?
